# Alternative to cron job in linux for running a script after every M minutes?

Tags: linux, cron

I need to run a script file after every M minutes. This M is configurable. For now I have used the cron entry as below.

```
*/M * * * * /tmp/test.sh
```

But, by using above logic, M value is restricted to 5,10,15,30 etc., M can not be set to 28 for example. I can write a background service for doing this, but I wanted to know is there any alternative to cron job.

Comment: It depends on your system. Look at [systemd.timer](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html)

Comment: The easiest is to run your script using `at` jobs. At the end of the script, schedule itself to run `at now + 28 min`. This will ensure that the script will get executed 28 minutes after the last run.

Answer (score 1):

Define a cron job that runs every minute. Have it invoke a script that checks the current time, and executes your command only if the current time is a multiple of M.

One way to do this is to get the result of `date +%s` (which is the number of seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT), divide by 60 to get minutes, and then compute the remainder modulo M.  In bash:

```
M=28
curr_second=$(date +%s)
curr_minute=$((curr_second / 60))
if (( curr_minute % M == 0)) ; then
    # run your command
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way to implement it using `at` jobs.

In your script you add a line that schedules itself 28 minutes after the current run or 28 minutes after the current start, depending on what suits your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash
#uncomment if it requires to start next run 28 minutes after this script started regardless of how long this job runs
# at now + 28 min < $0
# The rest of your commands go here...
# commands ....
# uncomment if it's desired to start the next run 28 minutes after this job ends
# at now + 28 min < $0
```

Hope this helps. If your script requires a specific shell, set the SHELL environment while invoking `at` like `SHELL=/bin/bash at now + 28 min < $0`.